# Google Chrome information bar

Tags: google-chrome

I added an extra parameter to Chrome "--disable-web-security". After I add this the "same origin policy" gets disabled which is exactly what I want.
The problem is that when I start Chrome an yellow information bar appears at the top and says:
"You are using and unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer."
The weird thing is that the flag seems to be supported as I tested Chrome with and without it.

My question is: Can that information bar be disabled with another flag or any other way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try going to about:flags in the address bar and disabling Native Client..

Comment: That option was already disabled. I enabled it and then disabled it again but with no effect.

Comment: Here is the right syntax. Working for me..    C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe –allow-file-access-from-files –disable-web-security

Comment: I tried that also but with no luck :|. My chrome version is 21.0.1180.89 and I'm using win7 .... if that helps.

Comment: I think this no longer work correctly by adding paramters. Try with Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/)

Comment: Forcecors is super. Worth mentioning that after installing you have to click view => toolbars => add-on bar. Then the cors button will show in the right bottom click on that to enable it. I unzipped the xpi and see there is a toggle function when a button was pushed but never see the button.